# 96 Olds Cutlass Supreme 3.1L Is it the alternator?

Tags: alternator, ignition, oldsmobile

Is it the alternator?? When I put the key in the ignition all my lights come on bright, the icons on my display light up & my radio works BUT when you turn the key car won’t turn over & you completely lose power.  The battery is 2 years old.

Answer (score 2):

From the symptoms you describe, I would be certain that it is not your alternator.

This sounds more like a fault in your ignition switch.  It would appear that the switch is not keeping the power connected when you turn to the start position.

With the ignition on, do all the other ancillaries work, like the wipers, headlights, horn etc?  Try turning as many on as possible at the same time to see if the battery can supply power to them all and report back.

If you are able to put the battery on a charger for a few hours and try starting again, this would help in the diagnosis too.

A faulty alternator would just mean that the battery would become flat with use of the car.  But your first symptoms would including the starter struggling to turn the engine and then a buzzing noise from the starter solenoid as you try to start.

If you have access to some jump leads, you could also try jump starting from another battery.  If the lights still go out when you turn the ignition, then it would indicate trouble with the switch.

If you can start the engine after charging the battery or using jump leads, then maybe your battery was just flat and then it could be due to a faulty alternator not keeping it charged.

Comment: It could also be the battery connection itself. If the amperage needed to turn the starter overcomes the connection, it can lose the connection momentarily when the ignition is in the start position, then regain enough connection to run the auxiliaries once the ignition is back to the on position.